# Get set value attribute with Knockoutjs

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, knockout.js

I have a Input tag and input value that is Knockoutjs function. I want to take the value of that input and put in facebook share data-href attribute can you please help.
Here is the code

I want to take this this data-bind="value: generatedLink" value

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: generatedLink" readonly id="copyClip">
```

and put it in "data-href"

```
    <div class="fb-share-button fb-Button" data-href="" data-layout="button" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true" style="margin-right:20px; float:right">
                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oppa.ge%2Fpiggybank%2F1002102&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" style="height:45px;">Share</a>
            </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
```

generatedlink

```
piggyBankViewModel.prototype.shareLink = function (id, data) {
$.get('/PiggyBank/GetShareLink/' + id, function (response) {
    data.canShowShareContainer(true);
    data.shareLinkValue(response.link);
    data.generatedLink(response.link);
});
```

Comment: What is data? And are you calling ko.applyBindings on piggyBankViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the `attr` binding. [attr documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html)

```
data-bind="attr: { 'data-href': generatedLink }"
```